# C# get URL query string Request.QueryString not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL like so `api/getListItems?data=false`

how would I get the query parameter data? I tried using Request.QueryString but I get an error 'The type or namespace name 'Request' could not be found' I have the System.Web referenced installed, the version is 4.0.0.0 and the .NET Framework is 4.5...is there something I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: show your code... Request.QueryString should be populated if your code is in the correct spot.

Comment: Is getListItems a WebForms Page (aspx) or an HttpHandler (ashx) or MVC?

Comment: maybe Request["data"] works for you, check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do this :

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

String data= url.Split('?')[1].Split('=')[1];
```

thanks

Comment: this works, but data now equals data=false, how do i get false?

Comment: see edit just now I've split using ('=') to get the False, I mean if you have data equals data=false, then just do this string dataValue=data.Split('=')[1]; //this would give you False

Answer (score 2):

This is how I read data from querystrig:

```
bool Data = Boolean.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["data"]);
```